# Invalid XML character §

Tags: html, xml, xhtml

I am having a issue with characters in my XML when I view it on a website. The character I want to be put in is § and what is coming out is Â§ and my xml is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: wrong encoding maybe ? did you try setting it as utf-8 ?

Comment: Please show a full XML document.

Comment: try using the html code for your `§` character, which is `&#167`

Comment: Omg I love you lol. the &#167; worked! How did you find out that was the code for it? I couldnt find that anywhere!

Comment: lol there are plenty of code maps out there, ill post an answer in a sec xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of the character `§` you can use its html code which is either `&#167` or `&sect`.

have a look here [Ascii Code](http://www.ascii-code.com/), every ascii symbol has a dedicated html code that can be used instead of the symbol.

like the unbreakable space which i am sure you are familiar with: `&nbsp`

Answer (score 1):

If you see “§” as “Â§”, then the reason is usually that the data contains “§” [SECTION SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a7/index.htm) U+00A7 as UTF-8 encoded, as bytes 0xC2 0xA7, but it is being misinterpreted as being in an 8-bit encoding like windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1. Alternatively, an incorrect character code conversion (“double UTF-8 encoding”) has taken place.

Check out the HTTP headers of the web page. If they declare an encoding other than UTF-8, they may override the in-document declaration.